# How to scrub through a string to match a date

Tags: excel, vba

So I have built a workbook for validation and publishing sets of other workbooks/reports out to another location. Part of the process is for the user to enter a date value into a cell, and that is checked for within the reports the user has listed.

Date formatting doesn't matter because I am doing a date type to date type comparison in my validation function.

Basically:

```
if CDate(UserVal) = CDate(ValFromString) then
    'do stuff
end if
```

The other common occurrence is the date has always been at the end of the string in the compared cell.

**Example:**

```
Current 52 Weeks Ending 04/10/15
Cur 52 Weeks Apr 4, 2015
Current 52 WE 4-Apr-15
```

No matter what format the user inputs into the validation cell, I just keep stripping from the right until `isdate` pops true.

I know I have been lucky in this setup, with the date always being at the end. I've now run into two instances that do not work.

```
CURRENT 12 WEEKS (4 WEEKS ENDING 04/11/15)
4 WE 04/11/2015 Current 12
```

In the first, the parenthesis breaks my `right()` stripping. In the second, the date is in the middle. The format of the date value differs from report to report, so I cannot do a `instr(1, String, cstr(UserVal))` to accomplish the check. The location of the date is not set in stone either, as it could be at the end, beginning, or anywhere in the middle of the string.

Short way of putting it, is there an easy way to scan a string for a specified date value, agnostic of format?

Comment: Is there always a **space** character immediately preceding the date ??

Comment: I just thought of several other combinations which make the extraction a little difficult. Need sometime with this code...

Comment: Quick question. Would you consider strings as these as dates as well? `12.12.12`?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Not always.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't think I've ever seen that pop up in our data. I'ma gonna sayah no. But good catch.

Comment: Dates can be in so many formats. If you have some specific formats in mind then we can concentrate only on those. For example `DD/MM/YYYY`, `MMM DD YYYY`, `DD-M-YYYY`, `D-M-YY` etc...

Comment: Sorry took some time but did come up with something :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will find a date if it is there, but it may not be the date you want:

```
Sub INeedADate()
  Dim st As String, L As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  st = ActiveCell.Text
  L = Len(st)

  For i = 1 To L - 1
    For j = 1 To L
      st2 = Mid(st, i, j)
      If IsDate(st2) Then
        MsgBox CDate(st2)
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

The routine generates all properly sequenced sub-strings of a string and tests each one for *IsDate()*

The problem is that for:

**Current 52 Weeks Ending 04/10/15**

It finds the sub-string:

**04/1**

first - which is a valid date!!

Do you want ALL valid dates within the string ???

**EDIT#1:**

The solution is to just run the length part of the *Mid()* function backwards:

```
Sub INeedADate()
  Dim st As String, L As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  st = ActiveCell.Text
  L = Len(st)

  For i = 1 To L - 1
    For j = L To 1 Step -1
      st2 = Mid(st, i, j)
      If IsDate(st2) Then
        MsgBox CDate(st2)
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, and is amazing. Thanks so much! :) (The second one)

Comment: @JHStarner  Even the second one can be "enhanced"

Comment: Already doing so. Turning it into a function so I can simply reference it in the comparison. Thanks! :D

Comment: @JHStarner  If you require any further assistance, just update your post and leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my feeble attempt :D

This will match a wide range of date formats

Hope this helps

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr(1 To 5) As String, frmt As String
    Dim FrmtAr, Ret
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    MyAr(1) = "(This 01 has 04/10/15 in it)"
    MyAr(2) = "This 04/10/2015"
    MyAr(3) = "4-Apr-15 is a Sample date"
    MyAr(4) = "(Apr 4, 2015) is another sample date"
    MyAr(5) = "How about ((Feb 24 2012)) this?"

    '~~> Various date formats
    '~~> YYYY (/????) grouped together. Will search for this first
    frmt = "??/??/????|?/??/????|??/?/????|??-??-????|"
    frmt = frmt & "?-??-????|??-?-????|??? ?? ????|??? ? ????|"
    frmt = frmt & "?-???-????|???-??-????|???-?-????|"
    frmt = frmt & "??? ??, ????|??? ?, ????|"

    '~~> YY (??) grouped after. Will search for this later
    frmt = frmt & "??-???-??|?-???-??|??/??/??|?/??/??|??/?/??|"
    frmt = frmt & "??-??-??|?-??-??|??-?-??|???-??-??|???-?-??|"
    frmt = frmt & "|??? ?? ??|??? ? ??|??? ??, ??|??? ?, ??|"

    FrmtAr = Split(frmt, "|")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        For j = 0 To UBound(FrmtAr)

            'Something like =MID(A1,SEARCH("??/??/??",A1,1),8)
            Expr = "=MID(" & Chr(34) & MyAr(i) & Chr(34) & ",SEARCH(" & _
                   Chr(34) & Trim(FrmtAr(j)) & Chr(34) & _
                  "," & Chr(34) & MyAr(i) & Chr(34) & ",1)," _
                  & Len(Trim(FrmtAr(j))) & ")"

            Ret = Application.Evaluate(Expr)

            If Not IsError(Ret) Then
                If IsDate(Ret) Then
                    Debug.Print Ret
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

**EDIT**

You can also use this as an Excel function

Paste this in a module

```
Public Function ExtractDate(rng As Range) As String
    Dim frmt As String
    Dim FrmtAr, Ret
    Dim j As Long

    ExtractDate = "No Date Found"

    '~~> Various date formats
    '~~> YYYY (/????) grouped together. Will search for this first
    frmt = "??/??/????|?/??/????|??/?/????|??-??-????|"
    frmt = frmt & "?-??-????|??-?-????|??? ?? ????|??? ? ????|"
    frmt = frmt & "?-???-????|???-??-????|???-?-????|"
    frmt = frmt & "??? ??, ????|??? ?, ????|"

    '~~> YY (??) grouped after. Will search for this later
    frmt = frmt & "??-???-??|?-???-??|??/??/??|?/??/??|??/?/??|"
    frmt = frmt & "??-??-??|?-??-??|??-?-??|???-??-??|???-?-??|"
    frmt = frmt & "|??? ?? ??|??? ? ??|??? ??, ??|??? ?, ??|"

    FrmtAr = Split(frmt, "|")

    For j = 0 To UBound(FrmtAr)

        'Something like =MID(A1,SEARCH("??/??/??",A1,1),8)
        Expr = "=MID(" & Chr(34) & rng.Value & Chr(34) & ",SEARCH(" & _
               Chr(34) & Trim(FrmtAr(j)) & Chr(34) & _
              "," & Chr(34) & rng.Value & Chr(34) & ",1)," _
              & Len(Trim(FrmtAr(j))) & ")"

        Ret = Application.Evaluate(Expr)

        If Not IsError(Ret) Then
            If IsDate(Ret) Then
                ExtractDate = Ret
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
End Function
```

[image]

**Note**: I am still working on a `RegEx` version which will be pretty much shorter than this...

**Edit**: As promised! I am sure it make me made more perfect but now I can't spend more time on this :)

**RegEx Version**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr(1 To 5) As String

    MyAr(1) = "(This 01 has (04/10/15) in it)"
    MyAr(2) = "This 04/10/2015"
    MyAr(3) = "4-Apr-15 is a smaple date"
    MyAr(4) = "(Apr 4, 2015) is another sample date"
    MyAr(5) = "How about ((Feb 24 2012)) this?"

    For i = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print DateExtract(MyAr(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Function DateExtract(s As String) As String
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
    Dim sPattern As String

    sPattern = "\b(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)"
    sPattern = sPattern & "\s(\d\d?),?\s+(\d{2,4})|(\d\d?)[\s-]("
    sPattern = sPattern & "jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec"
    sPattern = sPattern & ")[\s-,]\s?(\d{2,4})|(\d\d?)[-/](\d\d?)[-/](\d{2,4})\b"

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        If .Test(s) Then
            Dim matches
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            With matches(0)
                a = .SubMatches(0) & .SubMatches(3) & .SubMatches(6)
                b = .SubMatches(1) & .SubMatches(4) & .SubMatches(7)
                c = .SubMatches(2) & .SubMatches(5) & .SubMatches(8)
                DateExtract = a & " " & b & " " & c
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Yours is a very clever approach!  My approach relies on whatever intelligence *CDate()* may possess.

Comment: Thanks Gary for appreciating it :)